# How do you propagate transactions across client-server RabbitMQ services?

Tags: transactions, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I'm trying to understand how [transactions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#transactions) work, so I've created a very simple example with a client & a server that both read & update a flat entity. Both are spring-boot 2.5 projects, using spring-amqp 2.3.6.

###### Client

```java
    @Transactional
    public void updatePerson(long personId, PersonDto personDto) {
        // read the entity...
        Message emailUpdateResponse = rabbitTemplate.sendAndReceive("person", "email.update", emailUpdateRequest);
        // further process the entity...
    }
```

###### Server

```java
    @Transactional
    @RabbitListener(
        id = "personListener",
        bindings = @QueueBinding(
            value = @Queue(value = "person.email.update", durable = "true"),
            exchange = @Exchange(value = "person"),
            key = "email.update"
        )
    )
    public Message updateEmail(@Payload EmailUpdateDto emailUpdateRequest) {
        // process the entity
        // return a Message with either OK or NOT_FOUND
    }
```

Then following the documentation, I've decided to set the `channelTransacted` flag to `true`:

###### Client

```java
@Configuration
public class RabbitConfiguration {
    private final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    public RabbitConfiguration(RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate) {
        this.rabbitTemplate = rabbitTemplate;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    protected void init() {
        // add support for transactions
        rabbitTemplate.setChannelTransacted(true);
    }
}
```

###### Server

```java
@Configuration
public class RabbitConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        factory.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        factory.setConcurrentConsumers(3);
        factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(10);

        factory.setChannelTransacted(true);

        factory.setDefaultRequeueRejected(false);
        return factory;
    }
}
```

Both projects use JPA, so the transaction manager is `JpaTransactionManager`.

Now when I run these, the request makes its way into the server just fine, no issues there, but then on client side I always get this error:

```
2021-07-13 11:27:57,417 ERROR [AMQP Connection 127.0.0.1:5672] CachingConnectionFactory: Shutdown Signal: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - channel is not transactional, class-id=90, method-id=20)
2021-07-13 11:27:57,566 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [dispatcherServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/service1] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.io.IOException] with root cause
com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - channel is not transactional, class-id=90, method-id=20)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.asyncShutdown(ChannelN.java:517)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.processAsync(ChannelN.java:341)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:182)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:114)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.readFrame(AMQConnection.java:739)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.access$300(AMQConnection.java:47)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:666)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
2021-07-13 11:28:02,372 ERROR [rabbitTemplate#0-consumerMonitor-1] DirectReplyToMessageListenerContainer: Consumer canceled - channel closed SimpleConsumer [queue=amq.rabbitmq.reply-to, index=0, consumerTag=amq.ctag-xbI0h8h8-eSbu36BATLJKw identity=486f9300]
2021-07-13 11:28:02,410 INFO  [rabbitTemplate#0-consumerMonitor-1] DirectReplyToMessageListenerContainer: SimpleConsumer [queue=amq.rabbitmq.reply-to, index=0, consumerTag=amq.ctag-fTwSAIEAp_fzzjf2ZU5dHQ identity=4d224dec] started
```

I've debugged it a bit, looking at how the `DirectReplyToMessageListenerContainer` is created & I can see there's no transaction semantics on it (i.e. `isChannelTransacted()` returns `false` & `transactionManager` is `null`), but then this instance is created by `RabbitTemplate` itself, not via any factory or anything similar, so it looks like it's out of reach for devs to customize it.

What am I missing or what am I doing wrong?
Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use transactions for `sendAndReceive()` operations - the server won't see the request message until the transaction commits.

Comment: Alright, I switched to `RabbitTemplate.send()` & that seems to work fine  I now have a starting point. Thank you sir!